# Use value inside variable in dplyrs left_join

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyeval

I have a variable like this:

```
name = "ID"
```

and i want to use the value (`"ID"`) to join a dataframe to another like this:

```
left_join(df1, df2, by=c(name = "col_to_join")
```

but I again don't know how to do this :/

#### with a little example

```
a = mtcars %>%
  select(1:3)

b = mtcars %>%
  select(3:5)

var_to_join = "disp"

# i know this could be done by just "disp"
# But the question is more on how to use a variable inside the by-argument
left_join(a, b, by = c(var_to_join = "disp"))
```

Comment: I don't understand - can you add a minimal reproducible example with the expected output?

Comment: sure, just a second. I gave a very quick example

Comment: Isn't it simply `left_join(a, b, by = "disp")`?

Comment: yes in this case it it, but lets imagine that the `var_to_join` would be something else

Comment: Please provide an actual example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stats::setNames()` or `rlang::set_names()` to create a named vector:

```
var <- "bar"
setNames("foo", var)
#>   bar 
#> "foo"
```